# GO CD - Fetch materials on failure

Tags: go-cd

The way "fetch" materials works is that the latest "passed" build is transferred to the downstream pipelines. 
Is it possible to do even if the upstream stage fails ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a stage failure even triggers the next stage or next pipeline, so nothing runs that could fetch the failed material.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do even if the upstream stage fails ?

**No.** It's not possible.

"Stages are meant to run sequentially". Why?

Mostly you should design your problem using stages in a way that they are dependent and sequential.

Like, **"build > unit test > integration test > deploy**.

If you look at the sequence above, it doesn't make sense to continue to next step if the previous one fails. So in go-cd stages are implemented to achieve this dependency pattern.

Maybe your requirement might be correct, but stages might not be the solution for that problem. I would suggest you re-think about why you want to do that and use correct abstraction in go-cd for that problem.

Gocd has pipelines,stages,jobs and tasks. Check what best fits your situation and apply it.